# Grid css box size

Tags: css, grid

https://www.arhantayoga.org/wall-of-love-2/ 
i am using following css for grid layout. But some box size gets large creating spaces. Like see the second review with girl image. How can i avoide extar space ?

```
.review_listing {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
    margin: 40px;
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I think it should be the `.comment-review-inner` issue, not the `.review_listing`, I change `.comment-review-inner` to `margin-bottom: 0;` then it space evenly

Answer (score 0):

The review boxes should not have a `margin-bottom`. That is why you have large spaces created.

If you want to keep that gap between each row, use this:

```
.review_listing {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
    margin: 40px;
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
}
```